# Chernoff bound - amplifying success probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

I am reading about an attack on some cryptosystem and they uses Chernoff bound to amplify the attacker's success. The simplfifed version is: An attacker can distuingish A from B with an advantage $\epsilon$. If he repeats this experiment $1/\epsilon^2$ times then his advanatage will be at least 1/2.

I have tried to search online for an explanation but I couldn't find any that I would understand. How is Chernoff bound used to derive the number of repetitions $1/\epsilon^2$?